# PDF File is not getting downloaded. Ajax call failing with transfer-encoding as chunked

Tags: ajax, spring

I am working on an application which allows the user to download a file on a button click. on click of a button I make an ajax call and that calls a spring controller. Inside that spring controller i have written a function as below:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/downloadFile", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String dowloadPDF(final HttpSession session, final HttpServletResponse response,@RequestParam(value="param1", required=true)final String param1,@RequestParam(value="param2",required=true)final String param2,@RequestParam(value="param3", required=true)final String param3,@RequestParam(value="fileName",required=true)final String fileNameRecieved){
final String fileName = fileNameRecieved.trim();
final String requestedFile = getPath(param1,param2,param3,fileName);

try{
File pdfFile= new File(requestedFile);
final InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(pdfFile);
response.setContentType("application/pdf");

response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename="+fileName);
IOUtils.copy(inputStream, response.getOutputStream());
response.flushBuffer();
inputStream.close();    
}catch(Exception exception){
System.out.println("stckTrace :  "+exception.getStackTrace());
exception.printStackTrace();
}
return "success";
}
```

and the ajax call written on a button click is as below.

```
$.ajax({  
url : "downloadFile",   
method : "GET",   
dataType: "json",
contentType: 'application/pdf',
'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked',
sync:true,
data:{
"param1" :param1,
"param2":param2,
"param3" :param3,
"fileName": fileName
},    
success : function(response) {
alert(response);
},
error : function(e) {  
alert('Error: ' + e.getAllResponseHeaders());   
}
});
```

The problem is my controller is getting called and executed without giving any exceptions. but no file was not downloaded and also i am getting error in the response of ajax call stating that

```
"Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=GATE-CS 2004.pdf
Content-Type: application/pdf
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Thu, 05 Feb 2015 16:33:22 GMT
"
```

Any one can please help me on this, I have changed the content type in ajax call as well, still it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

One problem seems to be related with `dataType` and `contentType` in the `ajax` call.

I think you have swapped their value in ajax call.As per your problem description ,their value should be.

```
dataType:'application/pdf','Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'

contentType : "json"//but you don't need to use it,because you are not sending the json data
```

Comment: don't set contentType,just use dataType as i said.did you debug the backend?

Comment: Yes my Controller is getting called properly, I have removed the  contentType attribute from their. but still getting the same error.

Comment: If iam using a simple href tag in jsp and try to call the controller then it is working properly and the file gets dowloaded but with the ajax call it is not working.

Comment: did the error function execute on response from server?

Comment: Yes, it executes every time i click on button.

Comment: It seems, that there is no solution for this problem, I googled alott but every where people have followed different approaches and also are using different plugins. If someone has something please help me on this.